# Dynamically add Button to ArrayList in Android app

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
String[] citazioni = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citazioni);
List<String> CitazioniOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String value : citazioni) {
    CitazioniOutput.add(value+"\n<Button android:layout_width=\"wrap_content\" android:layout_height=\"wrap_content\" android:text=\"@string/share\" android:onClick=\"Condividi("+value+")\" />");
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CitazioniOutput);

ListView listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewCitazioni);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I added the text "`<Button android:layout ...`" to each `CitazioniOutput` item. I would like to convert this text into an actual `Button`.

@Raghunandan: yes, I would like to add the share button for every item :)

Comment: you want a button for each row in listview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a custom listview with custom adapter. Use a custom layout for listview item. Add a button in custom layout file. There are plenty of tutorials in web how to do this. 
Check these links

[Custom Listview - Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

[Listview - Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't translate text values into new views))

If you want to add button into each row, please use custom view:
[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)